# TypeError: Cannot read property 'main' of undefined - React problem

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, material-ui

I am doing a simple webpage with React and I defined the following palette using in a theme using createMuiTheme from material-ui.

```
palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#333333"
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#727171"
    },
    background: {
    paper: "#f8f3f0",
    default: "#f8f3f0"
    },
    accent: {
      main: "#80d6d1"
    }
}
```

Then, when I want to use my accent color for some text I use:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  content: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
    minHeight: "90vh"
    color: theme.palette.background.main
  }
}));
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'main' of undefined

  71 |     minHeight: "90vh"
> 72 |     color: theme.palette.accent.main
  73 |   }
  74 | }));
```

Any ideas of what's wrong here?

Comment: There is no background attribute in the mallette object, you have only primary, secondary and accent

Comment: in fact there is, I skipped it here not to make it too long. I'll add it in order not to confuse (I didn't now it was necessary)

Comment: Use theme.palette.accent.main.

Comment: Try adding `console.log(theme.palette)` and make sure that an `accent` property exists.

Comment: Still theme.palette.background.main doesn't exist, there is no main !

Comment: Have you set the `ThemeProvider`

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that you import the  from '@material-ui/core' and **NOT** from '@material-ui/styles' in the App.js file.

I also made the same mistake and now everything is working perfect!

Thanks!

Comment: In my case, that was the problem, running locally styles worked fine, but on the cloud it didn't work, changing it for core worked